# How to use UISearchbar and Searchdisplaycontroller with multiple tableviews?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am currently trying to add some search-functionality to my app, but there are some problems, when configuring this. I have a tab-based application with 3 tableviews and I want to add **one searchbar for all** tableviews. But it seems not that easy to set this up.

The first problem that occurs is that inside the Storyboard-Editor I only can add a separate searchbar to every tableview, but it is not possible to add searchbar to the tabBarController itself. So that the same searchbar is visible over all 3 tableviews.

The Second Problem then is, if I get this some how working, I have to setup a searchDisplayController with 3 different tableviews, but i can initialize a searchDisplayController with just one tableview.

What is the best approach of searching 3 different categories with one searchbar on an iPhone and are there any tutorials out there ? I was also looking at some other apps like facebook, and they are also searching just inside one tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use three search display controllers as follows:  have each vc on each tab implement a method (and declare it publicly) like this:

```
- (void)searchFor:(NSString *)string {
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = string;
}
```

Each of those should implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

    // do the search logic for my table
    // set a badge on my tab indicating how many results I found

    // then perform it on the other vcs:
    NSMutableArray *otherVCs = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
    [otherVCs removeObject:self];

    for (MyViewController *otherVC in otherVCs) {
        [otherVC searchFor:searchString];
    }
}
```

You might need to make sure all your other tab vcs are loaded (if you launch the app, visit just one tab and try this, the other vcs might not be ready.  To do that, just insert this line in the loop to force the view to load:  `(void)[otherVC view];`

(note - this answer presumes ARC)

Comment: Yes, thats how it is for now. But i want to search 3 different categorys with one searchbar without presenting all the search-results in one tableview.

Comment: You mean, when the user is on any one of those tabs, and decides to search, you want the results to include results from all three tables?  That's fine.  Your search logic (shared or not shared) just needs to search all three models.  There are still three instances of the UI objects for searching because there are three tabs.

Comment: No not really :D. I try to explain what i want with this example: The user has selected tab 1, then he enters something into the searchbar. After pressing the search button, the results for the category 1 appears inside the tableview 1. Now the tabs should inidcate how many results are availabe in the other categorys. If i switch to category 2 the searchbar is still active with the current keywords and the tableview shows me the filtered results for category 2. If the user now presses the (x) inside the searchbar all 3 tableviews should show unfiltered Data.

Comment: Awesome,i'm curious about it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this out tomorrow. Now its time to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

there is a little Problem with this solution. It causes an infinite loop. The solution is that we have to proof if the view is visible or not.

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self setUpFilteredEndlessScrollingWithUrl:kGetAllTours];
    [self loadFilteredDataWithPath:kGetAllTours];
    if (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window) {
        NSMutableArray *otherVCs = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
        [otherVCs removeObject:self];

        for (BaseTableViewController *otherVC in otherVCs) {
            [otherVC searchFor:searchString];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```